# Sharing tethered NDIS connection over ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, connection, tethering, sharing

I'm trying to share my tethered NDIS connection to another device using ethernet. The scenario is:

1. I have an android smartphone which is connected to a wireless hotspot.
2. Using USB tethering, i'm sharing my smartphones connection to my laptop.
3. Now I'm trying to share this tethered connection to my PS4 console, using ethernet.

Normally I would try using "Sharing" option like on this image:
[Sharing option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYDL.png)

However this tab is not available in my case: [No Sharing option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5H7k.jpg)

I've done this before, but only when my latop was directly connected to a WiFi and not when using USB tethered connection. Is sharing in this case even possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution! 
I had to disable DHCP on my smartphone WiFi connection, then set a static IP and finally set the custom DNS (I used open google dns). After disconnecting and connecting my USB tethered connection, the "Sharing" tab appeared on Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device and I was able to succesfully connect PS4 to the ethernet. I also had to disable my ESET firewall for both of the connections.